# Как сделать, чтобы у пользователя была возможность сохранить?

Tags: ruby

Разрабатываю обычный блокнот на FXRuby. В нем сделал меню в котором пользователь может нажать "Create" и выведется новое окно, на котором пользователь может записать что-то. Но проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы у пользователя была возможность сохранить его "писанину". Нашел только метод `.getSaveFilename`, но не знаю как работать с ним.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сохранить файл в файле FXRuby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1127557/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5-fxruby)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте один и тот же вопрос дважды. Если нужно, вносите правки